# Finding the maximum non-zero matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix:

```
a = array([[ 2.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

what is the best way to find the maximum non-zero matrix(ie. matrix which is not fully zero) and  spanning all the elements, like

```
[[2.,3.],
 [0.,4.]]
```

I ve gone through numpy.nonzero which gives the indices of non zero elements but how can i use it efficiently to get the expected matrix?

the matrix must be square. I ve come up with this for now,

```
a[:np.nonzero(a)[0][-1]+1,:np.nonzero(a)[1][-1]+1]
```

It works. But does not seem to be elegant. Also it wont work if the matrix does not start at 0. Like,

```
[[0,0,2,3,0],
 [0,0,0,4,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

here the expected output is,

```
[[2,3],
 [0,4]]
```

Comment: By using the `min(index)` and `max(index)`?

Comment: Should the matrix be always square?

Comment: @chandan Could you be more specific on what you need in the desired output (properties of it) rather than the output itself

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: By the way the maximum non-zero matrix, in this case, is the original matrix itself. It has at least one non-zero element. The expected result in the question is incorrect.

Comment: By non-zero i mean not fully zero. So it is not the entire matrix

Comment: Why the answer is that instead of 4x4 matrix with all 0 except for the top-left element, which is 4?

Comment: I just want the biggest sub matrix which is square and not fully 0. So it is the top-left one as given

Comment: 4x4 matrix that @Andreas has mentioned is not fully 0 either. It has a "4" in it.

Comment: ok. I get it. I want the matrix spanning all the non-zero elements. So we cant take the 4x4 matrix suggested by @Andreas

Comment: Please edit the requirement in the question to include that

Comment: @Andreas added the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is not working for the second case is because your starting point for forming the matrix is always `0,0` since you always specify the end range.

This gets the minimum index of `np.nonzero` as the start range, and the maximum index of `np.nonzero` as the end range, in both axis. Therefore it is guaranteed to include all non-zero elements

```
a[np.min(np.nonzero(a)[0]):np.max(np.nonzero(a)[0])+1,
  np.min(np.nonzero(a)[1]):np.max(np.nonzero(a)[1])+1]
```

Comment: thanks. Had overlooked that. However, is this the best way?

Comment: Best in what way? Does it cover every cases? Most likely yes. Is it the most efficient in terms of performance? I'm not sure